# Second HDMI monitor only refreshes on mouse input

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, mouse, hdmi, monitor

I just installed Ubuntu 23.04 on my XMG Core 15. I also have a HDMI TV which I use as external monitor (it works well under Windows and Mac, so the monitor doesnt seem to be the issue).

Whenever I do anything on screen, I have to move my mouse for the HDMI screen to show it. On the laptop monitor it works just fine, but the HDMI monitor gets stuck until I move the mouse.

All the drivers are up to date (fresh installation), both screens don't flicker or anything, the screens don't appear to be smeared or anything. All is fine, except this issue.

Any ideas?

Edit: Okay, it doesn't matter that it's HDMI. I plugged in a standard monitor and it has the same flaw.